# Access encrypted home directory of one user when I am logged in as another user

Tags: 14.04, encryption, ecryptfs, cryptsetup

On Ubuntu 14.04 I have created an encrypted home directory for a certain user A (with `ecryptfs-utils` & `cryptsetup`). However I am usually logged in as another user B. When I am logged in as user B, how could I access the contents of the home directory of user A as if it was not encrypted?

For example, since user B is an Admin, and I have user B's login credentials, I am (kind of) able to see the contents of user A's home directory from nautilus, but all I see there is some encrypted stuff.

Answer (score 1):

User B being an admin does not mean it can decrypt the home directory of user A. The reason is that only when User A logs in the home folder is made available as if was not encrypted.

I believe this behavior is intended and it is - and should not be - possible.

Comment: Right, admin rights of user B should not be enough but I also have user A's credentials. I simply want to apply them while I am logged in as user B. I don't think it's impossible since if I cannot log into user A, I can still externally recover A's home directory by the encryption passphrase (which I also have). http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/

Comment: If you have the credentials, then try logging in. If I recall correctly the home folder is then accessible for other users as well. Does that work for you?

Comment: I do not want to log off user B in order to access the files in user A's home. I want to remain logged into user B but be able to access the files in user A's home.  I have all the required credentials, can't get any better here, the question is how I apply them in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I just founds this page looking for a similar solution and I can confirm I just did an su myuser and logged in from terminal

Then with root I could access all the files in myuser's home directory - actually using Mint but its based on Ubuntu so should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The ecryptfs mount overlays the existing home dir.  When you `sudo su - other-user` you become that user, but that doesn't mount the ecryptfs over the existing home dir.  For that you can use `ecryptfs-mount-private`.

related (my question):
[Do I need unencrypted files underneath encrypted overmount?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/755689/do-i-need-unencrypted-files-underneath-encrypted-overmount)